# How Does C++'s atoi work?

Tags: c++, atoi

So I have the following code:

```
void Start(int &year, string &mon, char &nyd)
{
    printf("%s", mon);
    int month= atoi(mon.c_str());
    printf("%i", month);
}
```

When the incoming parameter is "03" (the first printf shows 03), I got 0 for month.

However, if I add this line

```
mon = "03";
```

I got 3, which is correct, for month.

Why......????

**EDIT: I figured it out. You guys were right. DON'T use scanf for string input.**

Comment: You can't use `std::string` with `%s`.

Comment: So how do you suggest me to modify the code?

Comment: With an addition of `.data()` or `.c_str()`. Even better, stick with something better than `atoi`, such as `stoi`, which actually has error checking and more relevant to that line, `std::cout`, which is type safe for printing.

Comment: Nevertheless, the result of the atoi function, which is month, is not correct...

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: I simply do not know where to begin with you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't print std::string with `%s` in printf function, try this:

```
void Start(int &year, const std::string &mon, char &nyd)
{
    std::cout << mon << std::endl;
    int month= atoi(mon.c_str());
    std::cout << month << std::endl;
}
```

Or

```
void Start(int &year, string &mon, char &nyd)
{
    printf("%s\n", mon.c_str());
    int month= atoi(mon.c_str());
    printf("%i\n", month);
}
```

But std::cout is preferred over C printf function.

Also don't use scanf with std::string, use std::cin instead of scanf, std::cout instead of printf.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is not about the printf; it's about atoi. I still get 0 when mon = "03" after changing the printf function.

Comment: printf("Month: ");scanf("%s", month);Start(year, month, nyd);

Comment: @user1447343 Don't use scanf with std::string